# How to build pageview in column in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I want to create a ui in flutter like this

[image]

And I have managed it. As I have used pageview builder for this, it is asking for a page height, now the problem is that I have given the height according to this screen and now in mobiles with shorter screeen I am not able to get same results.

[image]

```
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.w, 20.h, 10.w, 3.h),
              height: 520.h,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: PageView.builder(
                        itemCount: controller.pages.length,
                        controller: controller.pageController,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return GridView.builder(
                              // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              gridDelegate:
                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                              ),
                              itemCount: controller.pages[index].length,
                              itemBuilder: ((context, index1) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    //some code
                                  },
                                  child: MenuTileWidget(
                                    title: controller
                                        .pages[index][index1].title,
                                    image: controller
                                        .pages[index][index1].image,
                                  ),
                                );
                              }));
                        }),
                  ),
                  SmoothPageIndicator(
                    controller: controller.pageController,
                    count: controller.pages.length,
                    effect: WormEffect(
                        activeDotColor: color2,
                        spacing: 14.w,
                        dotWidth: 16.sp,
                        dotHeight: 16.sp,
                        dotColor: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

And if I comment height, it gives exception.

Comment: Try  adding the error/exception in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `MediaQuery()` like this:

```
...
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.w, 20.h, 10.w, 3.h),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Column(
...
```

This is probably going to hide your indicators. So to solve this use `Stack()` instead of `Column()` then control the position of the indicator. Here is the full code:

```
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.w, 20.h, 10.w, 3.h),
              height: 520.h,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Expanded(///<- Remove this you won't need it anymore
                    child: PageView.builder(
                        itemCount: controller.pages.length,
                        controller: controller.pageController,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return GridView.builder(
                              // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              gridDelegate:
                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                              ),
                              itemCount: controller.pages[index].length,
                              itemBuilder: ((context, index1) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    //some code
                                  },
                                  child: MenuTileWidget(
                                    title: controller
                                        .pages[index][index1].title,
                                    image: controller
                                        .pages[index][index1].image,
                                  ),
                                );
                              }));
                        }),
                  ),
                  Align( ///<- Or Positioned
       alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
       child: SmoothPageIndicator(
                    controller: 
       controller.pageController,
                    count: 
       controller.pages.length,
                    effect: WormEffect(
                        activeDotColor: color2,
                        spacing: 14.w,
                        dotWidth: 16.sp,
                        dotHeight: 16.sp,
                        dotColor: 
 Colors.white),
                  ),
                )
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: replacing column with stack did the trick thanks.